# giving a error while calling a function in php that variable is undefined

Tags: php, function

I m using the following code in a PHP script I am trying to call a set of code through function `calling()`. When I call that function and run that script if shows me the error that the variable `$querydigit` is undefined.

Can any body tell me how I can call that set of code where I want it.

```
<?php 
//$querynum = $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];

    function calling()
    {
        if(isset($_GET[$querydigit]) && ($_GET[$querydigit]==1)) {$photoname = '1'; }
        else if(isset($_GET[$querydigit]) && ($_GET[$querydigit]==2)) {$photoname = '2';  }
        else if(isset($_GET[$querydigit]) && ($_GET[$querydigit]==3)) {$photoname = '3';  }
        else if(isset($_GET[$querydigit]) && ($_GET[$querydigit]==4)) {$photoname = '4';  }
        else if(isset($_GET[$querydigit]) && ($_GET[$querydigit]==5)) {$photoname = '5';  }
        else if(isset($_GET[$querydigit]) && ($_GET[$querydigit]==6)) {$photoname = '6';  }
        else if(isset($_GET[$querydigit]) && ($_GET[$querydigit]==7)) {$photoname = '7';  }
        else if(isset($_GET[$querydigit]) && ($_GET[$querydigit]==8)) {$photoname = '8';  }
    }


if(isset($_GET['1']))
{
$querydigit = 1;
$photoseries = 8;
$foldername = 'founder';
calling();
}

else if(isset($_GET['2']))
{
$querydigit = '2';
$photoseries = 8;
$foldername = 'founder';
calling;
}
}
?>
```

Comment: Define `calling` to accept an argument and pass the variable to it. Also, read about [variable scope](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php).

Comment: Also you can declare the variable as a global inside the function: 'global $querydigit;`.

Answer (score 4):

$querydigit is not defined within function's scope.
You can fix it in following way:

```
 function calling($querydigit) {
```

and then call your function like this:

```
calling($querydigit);
```

Here is your code fixed:

```
   <?php 
//$querynum = $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];

    function calling($querydigit)
    {
        if(isset($_GET[$querydigit]) && ($_GET[$querydigit]==1)) {$photoname = '1'; }
        else if(isset($_GET[$querydigit]) && ($_GET[$querydigit]==2)) {$photoname = '2';  }
        else if(isset($_GET[$querydigit]) && ($_GET[$querydigit]==3)) {$photoname = '3';  }
        else if(isset($_GET[$querydigit]) && ($_GET[$querydigit]==4)) {$photoname = '4';  }
        else if(isset($_GET[$querydigit]) && ($_GET[$querydigit]==5)) {$photoname = '5';  }
        else if(isset($_GET[$querydigit]) && ($_GET[$querydigit]==6)) {$photoname = '6';  }
        else if(isset($_GET[$querydigit]) && ($_GET[$querydigit]==7)) {$photoname = '7';  }
        else if(isset($_GET[$querydigit]) && ($_GET[$querydigit]==8)) {$photoname = '8';  }
    }


if(isset($_GET['1']))
{
$querydigit = 1;
$photoseries = 8;
$foldername = 'founder';
calling($querydigit);
}

else if(isset($_GET['2']))
{
$querydigit = '2';
$photoseries = 8;
$foldername = 'founder';
calling($querydigit);
}

?>
```

Comment: thanks for your reply. i have fixed it with calling that function code through a include file also and that works too for me.